# Why are there holes in the icing?

Tags: sculpting

I tried to follow the new Blender 2.8 tutorial from Blender Guru.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OTX3ZdYvEA

When entering "Sculpting" with the icing there were suddenly alot of holes in it. Why is this?[image]

Comment: does scaling down the donut help?

Comment: I think you might want to [upload your blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) file.

Comment: So glad you asked this question!

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>  in *Edit Mode* before apply modifier and you can solve this problem.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that T_T

Comment: This is my explanation: We hide some points of icing before and we have to unhide these points. But that wasn't showed in video.

Answer (score 1):

It's mentioned at around 8:40 in the video, but only very briefly (and doesn't mention the holes specifically) https://youtu.be/6OTX3ZdYvEA?t=517

Unhide the rest of the mesh before applying the subdivision modifier, [as mentioned above](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/152988/15543). Otherwise, the subdivision won't be applied everywhere/evenly I'm guessing?

I had the same problem and found the answer here, but thought it'd be good to point out that the step is in the tut, but is only very briefly mentioned and easily missed.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming Blender 2.80) It looks like you are using the bevel modifier and the subdivision modifier. Switch both (first becomes second and vice versa)