# why blender create holes in mesh when i go to sculpt mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

So, I am doing the "blender guru" tutorial, and when it's time to sculpt, my "icing" object creates this holes, anyone knows how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151044/why-are-there-holes-in-the-icing

Comment: Do you have any unapplied modifiers on your mesh when you go into sculpt mode?