# can a mesh be smooth without creating "holes"

Tags: mesh, multiresolution

Right now I try to smooth a quite big mesh to the piont you cant realy make out the eges in the final rendering. But every methode I found was just giving no result at all or downsize the singel "mesh tiles" and by that create holes in the mesh. From my understanding i need to enlarge the mesh "resolution" witch i tried with multires BUT the simple setting does nothing at all in my case and the Catmull-Clark setting creates the mentioned holes.

Original object
[image: Original Object]

Catmull multires
[image]

Comment: It could be that you've hidden vertices similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151044/why-are-there-holes-in-the-icing) or there's something broken in the geometry of the mesh, e.g. disconnected areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobertGützkow pointed out, this is caused by disconnected vertices.

1. Select all vertices (*Select > All*), <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Go *Mesh > Clean Up > Merge By distance*, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
3. Done.

[image]

Comment: This problem is caused by applying the "Edge Split" modifier to the mesh before the subdivision modifier. and this is the right answer to fix this problem :)

Comment: This can also happen during import - that faces are imported as separated, without any modifier applied :).

Comment: Tanks guys worked great :D