# Separated triangles in a UV editor

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a planar mesh which I would like to texture.  The issue is, this mesh is built (externally) using an algorithm which is agnostic with respect to orientation.  In particular, the mesh in question is not oriented consistently between adjacent elements, and the automatic UV assignment in Blender produces the picture below instead of a consistent texture map.

Is there a way to correct this within Blender?

[image: Pictured: element orientations and texture map]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What unwrapping method have you tried? Also, your mesh might have [Disconnected vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/173621/).

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your response.  I cannot find any disconnected vertices, and I have tried only the standard uv unwrap.  In reality, this is a mesh that has been deformed (externally) from a (similarly misoriented) square, and I would like to visualize the deformation with a texture.  I am very new to Blender, so it is possible that I am missing something simple.

Comment: Hey :). If *UV > Unwrap* produces separate triangles, that's because the vertices are disconnected. You need to [merge them](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/173632/78972) before unwrapping, to get a continuous UV map.

Comment: Thanks!  That must have been the issue, because I get more plausible results now.