# Inverse fuction to "Rip Region" to heal disconected faces

Tags: modeling, mesh

There is function ***Rip region*** (Rip polygon) which disconnects faces and creates [non-manifold mesh](http://sergio-matsak.blogspot.com/2017/12/mesh-has-non-manifold-uvs-clean-up-mesh.html)

Is there some ***inverse function*** which can heal it back ?

**background:**

I often create some meshes with disconnected faces, sometimes imported from different programs. I would like to Heal them - i.e. to make proper manifold mesh from them, sine they are more convenient for further editation

Comment: Hello :). There sure is. It's called *Merge by distance* https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/173621/

Comment: aha thanks, this is useful. But I search somethink like tool where I can choose which edge should be merged. In softimage XSI it was "Weld" function.

Comment: You can select which vertices to merge :). But there's also the *Weld* modifier, if you like non-destructive workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the *Weld modifier* (since 2.82) for non-destructive workflow.

You can use a vertex group to limit it's influence.

[image]