# Why can't I see the rest of the vertices on my object?

Tags: vertices

When I go into edit mode a ton of vertices just disappear.

[image]

Comment: maybe you've hidden them? in that case > Alt H

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there holes in the icing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151044/why-are-there-holes-in-the-icing)

Comment: Thanks so much!