# There are some blue lines in my mesh, and wherever they intersect, vertices are locked. How do i remove it?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I was following the donut tutorial. I applied all the modifiers, and then there were some blue lines in the mesh. In the place where there should be vertices, there is nothing and that is locked in place. They do not budge, even in proportional editing and sculpting. How do i remove it? I tried recalculating the normals, but it didn't work.[image]  .[image]   Please help me.

Comment: ALT + H to unhide vertices

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there holes in the icing?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151044/why-are-there-holes-in-the-icing)

Comment: The blue lines are Edge Bevel Weights used by the Bevel modifier. They should do no harm. You can get rid of them in Edit mode. Select all verts (A), open N-panel (N), select "Item" tab, and enter 0 in "Edges Data: Mean Bevel Weight"